# Category theoretic proof that $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I have been going through the proof of Theorem 9.4 in "Sets for Mathematics" by Lawvere and Rosebrugh, which proves that $1+\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}$, but I am a little confused over how to prove from that, that the successor map $\sigma:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is *not* surjective, which is the exercise 9.15. I know from corollary 9.6 in the book that $\sigma: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is injective since the predecessor map $p$ is a retraction for $\sigma$.

The definition of infinite is that of Dedekind, i.e. a set $X$ is infinite if there exists an $s:X \to X$ which is injective but not surjective.

Now, I though about using proof by contradiction, so that I suppose that $\sigma$ surjective, and get a contradiction from the fact that $\sigma$ surjective implies that $\sigma(n)=0$ for some $n$, but the proof of theorem 9.4 doesn't immediately suggest any relevant angle of attack on the problem.

In the proof of 9.4, one proves that $1+\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}$ by constructing an inverse $g:\mathbb{N} \to 1 + \mathbb{N}$ to the unique $f:1+\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ via recursion.

$g$ can be shown to satisfy:

$$ g(0) = i_\ast$$
$$ g(n+1)=i_\mathbb{N}(n)$$

Where $i_\ast:1 \to 1+\mathbb{N}$ and $i_\mathbb{N}:\mathbb{N} \to 1+\mathbb{N}$ are the injections into $1 + \mathbb{N}$.

$1$ denotes the terminal object in the category of sets, and $\mathbb{N}$ is a natural numbers object in the category of sets. All morphisms in the category are supposed to be total functions.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We demonstrate that $s$ is not an epimorphism, by constructing $u_0,u_1: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $u_0 \circ s = u_1 \circ s$ while $u_0 \neq u_1$; in fact, this works in any category where $s \neq \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb N}$, not just $\mathsf{Set}$.

Writing $!: \mathbb N \to 1$ for the terminal morphism, we let $u_0$ be the universal arrow in the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
1 @>{0}>> \mathbb N @>{s}>>\mathbb N\\
@VV{\mathrm{id}_1}V @VV{u_0}V @VV{u_0}V\\
1 @>{0}>> \mathbb N @>{0 \circ {!}}>> \mathbb N;
\end{CD}
$$
and we let $u_1$ be the universal arrow for
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
1 @>{0}>> \mathbb N @>{s}>>\mathbb N\\
@VV{\mathrm{id}_1}V @VV{u_1}V @VV{u_1}V\\
1 @>{s \circ 0}>> \mathbb N @>{0 \circ {!}}>> \mathbb N.
\end{CD}
$$
Now $u_0 \circ 0 = 0 \neq s \circ 0 = u_1 \circ 0$, because if $0 = s \circ 0$, then the universal arrow for
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
1 @>{s \circ 0 = 0}>> \mathbb N @>{s}>> \mathbb N
\end{CD}
$$
equals both $s$ and $\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb N}$. In particular, $u_0 \neq u_1$. However,
$$
u_0 \circ s = 0 \circ {!} \circ u_0 = 0 \circ {!} \circ u_1 = u_1 \circ s.
$$
Basically, this answer just uses recursion to give the two simplest distinct functions $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ which agree on all values but 0.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder though, where exactly the fact that $1 + \mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}$ comes in, in your presentation?

Comment: @Bartuc, I suppose that would lead to a different answer. If you know that the composition $\mathbb N \to 1 + \mathbb N \cong \mathbb N$ gives the successor function, then the inclusion $i: \mathbb N \to 1 + \mathbb N$ must be surjective. But if it were, that would mean that $1$ admits at most one morphism into any object in the category (leading to the case where $s = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb N}$).

Comment: How does it follows that $i:\mathbb{N} \to 1+\mathbb{N}$ is surjective from the fact that $f i = \sigma$, where $f:1 + \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is the isomorphism in question. And how does it follow that $1$ admits atmost one morphism into any set $X$ then? If I assume that $\sigma$ is surjective, then I can see that $i$ must be surjective too, but the rest is a little beyond my comprehension at the moment?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that we assume (towards a contradiction) that $\sigma$ is surjective. Then from $\sigma = fi$ it follows that $i$ must also be surjective, since $f$ is an isomorphism. Now if $f,g : 1 \to A$ are distinct, then let $k : \mathbb N \to A$ be any mapping (could be $f \circ {!}$), and note that the universal property of $+$ says that $f+k,g+k: 1 + \mathbb N \to A$ must be distinct. But since $s$ is surjective, this means that $(f+k) \circ s = k = (g + k) \circ s$ should be distinct. Hence if $s$ is surjective, then every object admits at most one morphism from $1$.